# How does force-attitude affect my character?

Tags: star-wars-edge-of-the-empire, star-wars-age-of-rebellion, star-wars-force-and-destiny

When creating a character for our Star Wars campaign<sup>1</sup>, I get to choose things such as the *beginnings* of my character, an *attitude towards the Force* as well as a *reason for adventure*.

While it is clear to me how the the first and the last influence my character as well as how the GM can interact with it from my experience with other systems, the middle one sounds like a complete game-mechanic (but I could be wrong).

<sub><sup>1</sup>e.g. [OggDude's Character Gen](https://www.legendsofthegalaxy.com/Oggdude/)</sub>

Comment: which FFG game are you playing? because an attitude towards the Force does not match with any in-game mechanics. In Force and Destiny, all species come with an excerpt explaining the cultural view of the Force, sometimes including traditions. I think this is more a character development question that might inform your GM what Motivation and Obligation/Duty/Morality might be adequate for your character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> “It’s an energy field created by all living things. It surrounds us and penetrates us; it binds the galaxy together.” - *Obi-wan Kenobi*
>
> “I find your lack of faith disturbing.” - *Darth Vader*
>
> “The dark side of the Force is a pathway to many abilities some consider to be unnatural.” - *Chancellor Palpatine*
>
> “I’m one with the Force. The Force is with me.” - *Chirrut Îmwe*
>
> "Hokey religions and ancient weapons are no match for a good blaster at your side, kid." - *Han Solo*
>
> "Don't try to frighten us with your sorcerer's ways, Lord Vader. Your sad devotion to that ancient religion has not helped you conjure up the stolen data tapes, or given you clairvoyance enough to find the rebels' hidden fort-..." [sound of choking] - *Admiral Motti*

If the character believes in the Force, but is not a Force user, it could mean any number of things. Is the character jealous of Force users? Afraid of them? In awe of them?

If the character does not believe, how do they react to use of the Force? Are they dismissive, like poor Admiral Motti? Do they believe technology is superior? Are they uncomfortable? Is there sufficient evidence to change their belief?

In other words... there is no specific rules weight to a character's attitude towards the Force, but it can have significant impact on how the character interacts with other members of the group or the population of the galaxy.

Even among those who believe in the Force, there are different opinions on what the Force actually is - adherents of the [Living Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Force/Legends) have a different perspective than those of the [Unifying Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unifying_Force). Game-wise, they select from the same powers, but what those powers *mean* (and which ones interest a given character) can be influenced by their beliefs.